# I need cycle a timer

Tags: jquery, html, timer, cycle, jquery-cycle

If you can help, I need help with a timer in the plugin jquery cycle. So I need to create a timer that will go down from 20 seconds down to 19, 18, 17 ... over the cycle. Do you can help me.

Comment: Please show a code snippet of what you have tried or where you are having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this. It counts down from 20 and when it reaches 0 it goes back to 20. If you don't want it to go back when it's zero, than replace "i = 20" with "return".
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kqhHB

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 20;
    setTimeout(count(i), 1000);
    function count(i) {
        $('#counter').html(i);
        i--;
        if(i < 0)
          i = 20;
        setTimeout(function(){ count(i); }, 1000);
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I know that for this timer over, but I knew to do that, in any case, thank you. I need a timer of 20 seconds but to go along with the slider now I'll explain exactly what I need. I have a slider that runs through the cycle plugin and it changes images every 20 seconds, but I need a timer to cycle because if not it can disrupt and confuse the picture changing with timer pocunu to change the image of the 2 or 3 secunde you reach 0 Do you have a way of doing this –